# Bison/Yacc, make literal token return its own value?

Tags: yacc, bison, token

Below is my rule, when i replace $2 with '=' my code works. I know by default all literal tokens uses their ascii value (hence why multi character token require a definition)

The below doesnt work. The function is called with 0 instead of '=' like i expect. is there an option i can set? (It doesn't appear so via man pages)

```
AssignExpr: var '=' rval            { $$ = func($1, $2, $3); }
```

In another piece of code i have `MathOp: '=' | '+' | '%' ...` hence why i am interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value for $2 in this context will be whatever the yylex function put into the global variable yylval before it returned the token '='.  If the lexer doesn't put anything into yylval, it will probably still be 0, as you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right, Bison just doesn't work that way.

You can easily fix it, of course:

- just declare a token for `=`, recognize it in your lexer, and return its semantic value, or...
- declare a production for it and return it with `$$`
  or...
- assign '=' to yylval in yylex()